# pipe (|) delimiter in a csv-read pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

I have cells in a coulmn that look like this

Laduz|Guerchy|Neuilly|Villemer

name of column is 'anciennes'

I want to count how many times '|' occurs in this column

Comment: So in general is it true to say that you are looking for the number of delimiters on each line of a csv file? Because that will always be one less than the number of elements...

Comment: please show a sample of your csv file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the vectorised [`str.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.count.html) for this:

```
In [69]:
import pandas as pd
import io
t="""data
Laduz|Guerchy|Neuilly|Villemer"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t))
df

Out[69]:
                             data
0  Laduz|Guerchy|Neuilly|Villemer

In [72]:
df['data'].str.count(r'\|')

Out[72]:
0    3
Name: data, dtype: int64
```